# Inverse of partitioned matrix, checking result

Tags: matrices

$A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, partitioned as
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11} & A_{12}\\
A_{21} & A_{22}
\end{bmatrix},$$
where $A_{11}$ has dimensions $k\times k$ and $A_{11}$ and $A_{22}$ are nonsingular. I've managed to prove that the inverse is:
$$A^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
(A_{11}-A_{12}A_{22}^{-1}A_{21})^{-1} &
-A_{11}^{-1}A_{12}(A_{22}-A_{21}A_{11}^{-1}A_{12})^{-1}\\
-A_{22}^{-1}A_{21}(A_{11}-A_{12}A_{22}^{-1}A_{21})^{-1} &
(A_{22}-A_{21}A_{11}^{-1}A_{12})^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}$$
However, I am having difficulty showing that $A^{-1}A=I$. For example, if I multiply the first row of $A^{-1}$ times the first column of $A$, I get:

$$(A_{11}-A_{12}A_{22}^{-1}A_{21})^{-1}A_{11}-A_{11}^{-1}A_{12}(A_{22}-A_{21}A_{11}^{-1}A_{12})^{-1}A_{21}$$

This should equal a $k\times k$ identity matrix, but I can't seem to show that this is the case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think the Woodbery identity property will help you:
   $ \left(A+UCV \right)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}U \left(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U \right)^{-1} VA^{-1}$

Comment: Excellent suggestion, and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form of $A^{-1}$ in your question follows from the usual derivation of [Schur complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement), but you may also directly verify that the formula is indeed a partitioned matrix inversion formula. For convenience, we relabel $A_{11},A_{12},A_{21},A_{22}$ as $X,Y,Z,W$ respectively. Then
\begin{align}
&\phantom{=}(X-YW^{-1}Z)^{-1}X-X^{-1}Y(W-ZX^{-1}Y)^{-1}Z\\
&= (X-YW^{-1}Z)^{-1}(X-YW^{-1}Z+YW^{-1}Z)-X^{-1}Y(W-ZX^{-1}Y)^{-1}Z\\
&= I+\left[(X-YW^{-1}Z)^{-1}YW^{-1}-X^{-1}Y(W-ZX^{-1}Y)^{-1}\right]Z.
\end{align}
So, the question is whether the expression inside the pair of square brackets is zero. However,
\begin{align}
&(X-YW^{-1}Z)^{-1}YW^{-1}=X^{-1}Y(W-ZX^{-1}Y)^{-1}\\
\Leftrightarrow\ &YW^{-1}(W-ZX^{-1}Y)=(X-YW^{-1}Z)X^{-1}Y\\
\Leftrightarrow\ &Y-YW^{-1}ZX^{-1}Y=Y-YW^{-1}ZX^{-1}Y.
\end{align}

Comment: Very nice move.